# d3 tree layout to display text on mouse hover over links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am using d3 tree layout to construct a graph and am using diagonal elements to construct links between the nodes.I wanted to display certain text when mouse is hovered on links. Is nested hovering possible?

```js
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "my-tooltip") //add the tooltip class
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "hidden");


var flare = {
  "name": "Base",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Type A",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Section 1"
    }, {
      "name": "Section 2"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Type B"
  }]
};
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


//d3.json("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json", function(error, flare) {

root = flare;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);
//});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      var g = d3.select(this); // The node
      // The class is used to remove the additional text later
      var info = g.append('text')
        .classed('info', true)
        .attr('x', 20)
        .attr('y', 10)
        .text("Sample text to be displayed");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      // Remove the info text on mouse out.
      d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove();
    });



  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    })

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
        .text('SOURCE : ' + d.source.name + ' || TARGET : ' + d.target.name)
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 130) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });;

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Update the link text
  var linktext = svg.selectAll("g.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });
  linktext.enter()
    .insert("g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      //console.log(d.target.name);
      return d.target.name;
    })
    .on('mouseover',function(d){
    console.log('TEXT HOVER : ' + d.target.name)
    });


  // Transition link text to their new positions

  linktext.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + ((d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2) + "," + ((d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2) + ")";
    })

  //Transition exiting link text to the parent's new position.
  linktext.exit().transition()
    .remove();


  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  fill: #CC0000;
}

.my-tooltip {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: provide some code or make fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shak_k/zudxrd59/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would append a div to the body, set `visibility` to `hidden`, and on `mouseover` show the div at the position of the mouse.

So append the div like so :

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "my-tooltip")//add the tooltip class
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden");
```

Then on mouse over set the text (here I have just done an example and shown the source and target names :

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
        .text('SOURCE : ' + d.source.name + ' || TARGET : ' + d.target.name)
    })
```

Then on `mousemove` update position :

```
.on("mousemove", function() {
  return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 130) + "px");
})
```

And then hide it on `mouseout` :

```
.on("mouseout", function() {
  return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

And then you can append what ever you want. Just on the `mouseover` event on the link, just append to the `tooltip` :)

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/zudxrd59/5/

Dont forget the `CSS` too :

```
.my-tooltip {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also wanted to hover on the text that is already displayed by hovering

Comment: If you mean just hovering over the text. Look at my updated example : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/zudxrd59/6/, on line 224 of the Javascript is where I implement mouseover. You can do the tooltip here just copy what I have done for the links to the link text

Comment: I wanted to do something like nested hovering.

Comment: I dont think I understand. You want to hover over the tooltip too ?

Comment: Yes i want to hover on the tooltip again

Comment: Ok, well dont hide the tooltip on mouseout, and apply a mouseover event to the tooltip in the same way I did for the links. Apply this where I created the tooltip at the top of the page. Because you don't hide the tooltip on mouse out, I would recommend on clicking outside of the tooltip, so anywhere on the body, hides the tooltip. Otherwise it will always be shown

Comment: Thanks a ton. Got it :) It was so helpful

Comment: I have a doubt. how do i display a json value in the tooltip?  for example, if my json data contains {"value","Text 1 to be displayed"}, then is it enough if i give d.value in the tooltip text?

Comment: Why don't you try it out ?